# Bootstrap Trello-like horizontally scrollable board with containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Like the title says, I would like to implement a Trello-clone as an exercise in using Bootstrap. I want to have the top menu remain constant, where as the boards (columns) scroll along the X-axis.

I have tried using something like this, where the container has all  within it.

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#board-container{
  width: 100rem; // Wider than the viewport
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.board{
  width: 40rem;
  float: left;
}
```

But this isn't working.

How can I go about doing something like this? Can I do it with just HTML, and preferably with Bootstrap?

Comment: Check out: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/brmXRX

Comment: This fork has drag and drop functionality too which is pretty awesome: https://codepen.io/martinedozo/pen/VMZzLx

Comment: If I pull those examples out, and run them from my disk, the examples do not work properly in Chrome, but does in Firefox. Is any one able to reproduce the same result? In Chrome it works just fine in Codepen, but when run locally it messes up the height, and doesn't contain the height of the lists within the viewport, so you can scroll the main viewport.